# Filter query Filled JTable from ComboBox

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, combobox, jtable

I have a Jtable filled by a query from my Sql Table and i have some "ComboBox" that are also filled by a query, what i want is to be able to Filter the data of my Jtable based on the user ComboBox Select but i dont know how can i do this

This is my Sql.class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Sql extends JFrame{
JTable table = new JTable();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new     String[]{"fecha","clave_pdv","pdv","turno","clave_platillo","platillo","precio","total sin iva"});
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter;

Connection conn = null;
Connection conn1 = null;
Statement st = null;
Statement st1 = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSet rs1 = null;
//Create list of values


private final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
private final JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();



public Sql(){

    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ARTURO-LAPTOP;user=sa;password=sacompusis;database=PDV");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs= st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Nombre_Pdv FROM   VENTA_PLATILLOS");

        while(rs.next()){
            comboBox.addItem(rs.getString(1));  
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn1 =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ARTURO-LAPTOP;user=sa;password=sacompusis;database=PDV");
        st1 = conn.createStatement();
        rs1 = st1.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Nombre_Turno FROM   VENTA_PLATILLOS");
        while(rs1.next()){
            comboBox_1.addItem(rs1.getString(1));

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setBounds(139, 88, 535, 227);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    comboBox.setBounds(404, 11, 130, 31);
    getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    comboBox_1.setBounds(544, 11, 130, 31);

    getContentPane().add(comboBox_1);

    //Populate table
    sqlConection bd = new sqlConection();
    List<Value> values = bd.selectAll();
    for(Value v : values){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{v.fecha,v.clave_pdv,v.pdv,v.turno,v.clave_platillo,v.platillo,v.precio,v.total});
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            Sql ms = new Sql();
            ms.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            ms.pack();
            ms.setVisible(true);
        }});
}
}
```

And my Connection Class sqlConnection.class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class sqlConection {

public List<Value> selectAll(){
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    //Create list of values
    List<Value> values = new ArrayList<Value>();

    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://ARTURO-LAPTOP;user=sa;password=sacompusis;database=PDV");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("select Fecha,Clave_PDV,Nombre_Pdv,Nombre_Turno,Platillo,Nombre_Platillo,Precio,Total from VENTA_PLATILLOS");

        while(rs.next()){
            Value v = new Value();
            v.setFecha(rs.getDate("Fecha"));
            v.setclave_pdv(rs.getString("Clave_PDV"));
            v.setpdv(rs.getString("Nombre_Pdv"));
            v.setturno(rs.getString("Nombre_Turno"));
            v.setclave_platillo(rs.getString("Platillo"));
            v.setplatillo(rs.getString("Nombre_Platillo"));
            v.setprecio(rs.getFloat("Precio"));
            v.setTotal(rs.getFloat("Total"));


            values.add(v);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return values;
}
}
```

How can i make my "combobox" to sort my table items based on  user select??

Comment: Depending on what you want to do you could either re-query the database or simple sort the table as is, for more details see [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: I'd also suggest you have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify